# NoMethodError in Pages#welcome after installing the bootstrap gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

After I installed the `bootstrap` gem and run the `rails server` again I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#welcome
undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass
  (in /Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/prospects/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
```

#### custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

#### app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
      <title>Prospects</title>

      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <%= link_to "Home", "/" %>
        <%= link_to "About", "/about" %>

     <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### log/development.log

```
Processing by PagesController#welcome as HTML
  Rendered pages/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass
  (in /Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/prospects/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
    4:  <head>
    5:    <title>Prospects</title>
    6: 
    7:    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    8:    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    9: 
   10:    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3923576615849785590_70354614228980'
```

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

#### app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

updated the gemfile
ran bundle update

```
'ran bundle update Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.2) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0.rc1) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.0.rc1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue with how the `sass-rails` gem integrates with the `sprockets` gem which surfaced after the Sprockets v2.11.1 release (see [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/537) and [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/191)).

To fix it change the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
```

and run `bundle update`.

**Note:** You should also update your Rails version. The most recent version is [v4.0.4](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/3/14/Rails-4-0-4-has-been-released/). To do so, change your Gemfile to

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

and again, run `bundle update`.

Comment: yes working now after i updated the rails gem , in the future would it better if i used the boostrap cdn and copied the link to my application folder ,are there any pros and cons using the cdn method?? thanks..Neil

Comment: Using (or not) a CDN depends on you needs. Will you customize Bootstrap (e.g. different colors, gird sizes) or do you plan to integrate a [theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/)? Do you care about your users' privacy and/or do you want to use HTTPS? This is only a short list of reasons speaking *against* a CDN. On the other hand there are some benefits, but I think this is worth a separate question…